# Assertion in type definition

Tags: ocaml, assert

I have some type

```
type my_type_name =
    | A of (float * float)
    | B of (float * float)
    | E
;;
```

And I know that I have issue in my code, if `p >= q` in `B (p, q)` or `A (p, q)`. So I want to make assertion in type, such that if I'll try to make `A (5, 1)` it will inform me.

Is it possible to make assertion in type constructor? How it should look like?

I'm trying to avoid something like that:

```
assert (p < q) ; A(p, q)
```

Cause I have a lot of A or B objects in code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Jeffrey Scofield already gave a fully accurate answer to this, but here is the example requested:

```
module type MY_TYPE =
sig
  type my_type_name = private
    | A of (float * float)
    | B of (float * float)
    | E

  val a : float -> float -> my_type_name
  val b : float -> float -> my_type_name
  val e : my_type_name
end

module My_type : MY_TYPE =
struct
  type my_type_name =
    | A of (float * float)
    | B of (float * float)
    | E

  let a p q = assert true; A (p, q)
  let b p q = assert true; B (p, q)
  let e = E
end

let () =
  (* My_type.A (1., 2.); *)    (* Type error - private type. *)
  let x = My_type.a 1. 2. in

  (* Can still pattern match. *)
  match x with
  | My_type.A (_, _) -> ()
  | My_type.B (_, _) -> ()
  | My_type.E -> ()
```

The body of the signature could be an `.mli` file instead and the body of `My_type` could be an `.ml` file. The key is that `my_type_name` is followed by the keyword `private` in `MY_TYPE`. This causes the direct use of the constructor at the bottom to be flagged as an error, forcing all construction to go through the functions `a`, `b`, `e`, where you can include assertions or arbitrary other expressions.

**EDIT** To make the functions look even more like the constructors, you can of course turn their arguments into tuple types. To make the module nearly transparent you can `open` it at the bottom. But these are matters of taste and up to you.

Comment: antron, @JeffreyScofield: thanks to both of you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

There's no straightforward way to put such an assertion into the type definition itself.

One good approach would be to define your type as an abstract type (in a module) and export functions for constructing values of the type. These will be the only way to produce values of the type, and you can include any assertions you like in the functions.

**Update**

As @antron points out, making the type private rather than abstract might be a better fit for your problem.

Comment: As an improvement on this, you can make the type private instead of fully abstract, so you can still pattern-match on it, but have to construct it through the visible functions.